# onlogin event not being triggered

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this page (most of it is from the facebook documentation, with minor changes). Since I'm a n00b with this, I'm posting the whole code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reportes para Anunciantes</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function statusChangeCallback(response) {
            console.log('statusChangeCallback');
            console.log(response);
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // Logged into your app and Facebook.
                testAPI();
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into this app.';
            } else {
                // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
                // they are logged into this app or not.
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into Facebook.';
            }
        }

        // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
        // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
        // code below.
        function checkLoginState() {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        }

        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : '284483341757738',
                cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                // the session
                xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
                version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
            });

            checkLoginState();

            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
                statusChangeCallback(response);
            });
        };

        // Load the SDK asynchronously
        (function(d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
        // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
            });
        }
    </script>
    <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,ads_management" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
    <div id="status">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's time to analyze by parts.

1. A function which checks the facebook state and updates a div depending on if the user is not logged in @ facebook, if is logged in but the app not authorized, or finally if is logged in and authorized the app. The change is reflected in the dom. Such function is `statusChangeCallback`. Such callback is only called inside `checkLoginState` so each time the login state is checked, the callback is called.
2. A test api call, with a callback which updates the DOM with the results. The function is called `testAPI`.
3. The asynchronous load bunch. Once it is loaded, an initial call to `checkLoginState` is successfully performed.
4. A login button, with an `onlogin` event. The event calls, again, `checkLoginState`. This is to reflect the new login state in the dom.

My issue: **onlogin event is not being triggered**. Everything else works fine. **If I update the page** after logging in (facebook displays a login pop-up), I see the expected state (logged in), as a product of calling `testAPI`, **but that's not reflected until I refresh the page**. There's another way how I note this: after logging in, I should see a console message coming from `statusChangeCallback`, but such message neither appears, so I conclude such event is never triggered.

**Additional notes**: I'm testing my application in localhost (`http://localhost`). I enabled the localhost domain in my app (at developers.facebook.com), and enabled a "website" platform with base url of `http://localhost` (**I'm not using this app in a canvas**). The entry point of my site where I test everything is `/` (an index.html page). However, these messages appear in console:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost". Protocols, domains, and ports must match. VM3437:1
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
 VM3461:1
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
 VM3571:1
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://static.ak.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.      
 VM3627:1
statusChangeCallback
 (index):9
Object {authResponse: undefined, status: "unknown"}
 (index):10
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.facebook.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://localhost".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

So my **questions** are:

1. Why does the `onlogin` event not trigger after I log in?
2. Are these errors in console related? I'm using Apache. How can I solve them?
3. Is there a way -after a Graph API query (i.e. a GET call)- to know whether the user has logged out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe facebook's event handler. Add below code

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(){
// This alert box will appears if user successfully logined
// Do anything here....
alert("Successful Login");
});
```

so the updated code will be

```
  <html>
 <head>
  <title>Reportes para Anunciantes</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
  <body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        console.log('statusChangeCallback');
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into this app.';
        } else {
            // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
            // they are logged into this app or not.
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into Facebook.';
        }
    }

    // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
    // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
    // code below.
    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '284483341757738',
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
            // the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.0' // use version 2.0
        });

        checkLoginState();

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(){
       // This alert box will appears if user successfully logined
       // Do anything here....
       alert("Successful Login");
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
    // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    function testAPI() {
        console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
        });
    }
</script>
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,ads_management" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
<div id="status">
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```